# Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be independent events such that $P(E_1'\cap E_2)=\frac{2}{15}$ and $P(E_1\cap E_2')=\frac{1}{6}$. Then $P(E_2)$ is?

Tags: probability, systems-of-equations, independence

> Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be independent events such that
> $P(E_1'\cap E_2)=\frac{2}{15}$ and $P(E_1\cap E_2')=\frac{1}{6}$.
> Then $P(E_2)$ is?

What I tried:

1. Started in this way
   $$P(E_1\cap E_2') = P(E_1)-P(E_1\cap E_2)$$
   $$P(E_1'\cap E_2) = P(E_2)-P(E_1\cap E_2)$$
2. Now subtracted both in first point.
   what i got was
   $$P(E_1)-P(E_2)=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{2}{15}$$
   $$P(E_1)-P(E_2)=\frac{1}{30}$$
3. Since probability lies between 0 and 1,
   $$P(E_1)=\frac{1}{30}+P(E_2),$$
   $$0\leq P(E_1)\leq1,$$
   $$0\leq\frac{1}{30}+P(E_2)\leq1,$$
   $$0\leq P(E_2)\leq\frac{29}{30}.$$

The actual answer is given as 1/6 and 4/5. Please help me to derive the exact answer instead of range.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You haven't used the fact that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are independent events yet. Use that and you'll get some more equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(E_2)=x$.

Thus, since $P(E_1'\cap E_2)=P(E_1')P(E_2)$, by your work we obtain the following equation.
$$\left(\frac{29}{30}-x\right)x=\frac{2}{15},$$ which gives a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

As $ \small E_1$ and $ \small E_2$ are independent events, $ \small P(E_1\cap E_2) = P(E_1) P(E_2)~$
([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)))

So, $\small P(E_1\cap E_2^c) = P(E_1)-P(E_1\cap E_2) = P(E_1)-P(E_1) P(E_2) = \frac{1}{6}$

$ \small P(E_1)-P(E_1) P(E_2) = \frac{1}{6} \tag1$

$\small P(E_1^c\cap E_2) = P(E_2)-P(E_1\cap E_2) = P(E_2)-P(E_1) P(E_2) = \frac{2}{15}$

$ \small P(E_2)-P(E_1) P(E_2) = \frac{2}{15} \tag2$

As you found, $ \small P(E_1) = P(E_2) + \frac{1}{30}$

Now plug this in any of the above equations $(1)$ or $(2)$ and solve the quadratic equation to find $ \small P(E_2)$.